# Precondition on data pipeline

Tags: java, python, json, amazon-data-pipeline

I did some set of activities on json script. Need to add precondition on it.
how to use precondition on json script.

In precondition, i need to check the mysql db field. once flag as 'Y',
start execution else should be stop the execution.

Comment: {
 "id" : "InputData",
 "type" : "S3DataNode",
 "schedule" : { "ref" : "CopyPeriod" },
 "filePath" : "s3://example-bucket/InputData/#{@scheduledStartTime.format('YYYYMM-dd-hh:mm')}.csv",
 "precondition" : { "ref" : "Ready" }
},
{
 "id" : "Ready",
 "type" : "Exists"
}

Comment: am using code for precondition on datapipeline, but it is not working good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ShellCommandPrecondition for this which will let you write a custom precondition.

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "name": "DefaultResource1",
      "id": "ResourceId_dWoZ0",
      "type": "Ec2Resource",
      "terminateAfter": "1 Hour"
    },
    {
      "name": "DefaultPrecondition1",
      "id": "PreconditionId_yA2rV",
      "type": "ShellCommandPrecondition",
      "command": "<Script to check mysql field>"
    },
    {
      "occurrences": "1",
      "period": "1 Day",
      "name": "RunOnce",
      "id": "DefaultSchedule",
      "type": "Schedule",
      "startAt": "FIRST_ACTIVATION_DATE_TIME"
    },
    {
      "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "pipelineLogUri": "s3://<mybucket>",
      "scheduleType": "cron",
      "name": "Default",
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "name": "DefaultActivity1",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "ResourceId_dWoZ0"
      },
      "precondition": {
        "ref": "PreconditionId_yA2rV"
      },
      "id": "ActivityId_gmQ0W",
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
      "command": "echo 'Hello world'"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": []
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use VPC instead of using Ec2Resource ?